# Question regarding the definition of finitely generated graded ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $S = \oplus_{n \geq 0} S_n$ be a graded ring and $S_+ = \oplus_{n \geq 1} S_n$.
The notes (Ravi Vakil's online notes on algebraic geometry) I am reading defines the graded ring $S$ is finitely generated over $S_0$ if $S_+$ is a finitely generated ideal.

I was wondering if this is equivalent to $S$ being a finitely generated $S_0$ algebra?
If so, could someone be able to explain why the author chose the definition 
given rather than saying it is a finitely generated $S_0$ algebra? Thanks!

Comment: I think he gives the equivalence as an exercise. Have you kept on reading? Talking about the ideal being finitely generated probably puts you in a better state of mind for showing that $\operatorname{Proj} S$ has a finite cover by affine opens.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In fact I even did the exercise and I had forgotten about it... Thank you!

Comment: This is proved in Atiyah-MacDonald's next last chapter also.